# Perspective Projection Matrix appears to have incorrect FOV

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDX to write a "3D soft engine from scratch" as per a tutorial on MSDN. However, I cannot get my expected and actual fields of view to match up.

My now-simplified world comprises of four 3D vertices with Z=0 at (0,1,0);(0,-1,0);(1,0,0);(-1,0,0). I place the camera at (0,0,2) and look at (0,0,0) with (0,1,0) up. I setup the projection matrix with a FOV of 90 degrees (PI/2 radians) and prepare to render each of the four vertices by calling `Vector3.TransformCoordinate(Vector3, Matrix)`.

My understanding is that FOV is used to calculate a scale factor `1/TAN(FOV/2)` that can be applied to every (Y,Z) pair such that `y' = y * scale / z`. Similarly, given the aspect ratio, as scale is calculated for (X,Z) pairs too.

For a (vertical) FOV of 90 degrees and camera distance 2, I would have expected all of my vertices to be reasonably far from the edges of the bitmap. However, the top and bottom vertices have Y-values of -0.49 and +0.49 which means that they'd be practically touching the screen boundary if rendered. Have I misunderstood the concept of FOV? The results I'm seeing are what I'd expect from a FOV of about 53 degrees. It's as though the tangent is being halved before its inverse is taken...

I first tried this with the camera at (0,0,1) and FOV of 90 degrees because I felt sure that the scale factor would be 1 (`1/TAN(90/2) = 1`) but the vertices were off screen.

Comment: `0.49` is not at the screen edge. The viewport ranges from `-1` to `1` for ´x` and `y`. And therefore, the values seem reasonable. For a fov of `90°`, you see the range `-2` to `2` at a z-distance of `2`.

Comment: Thanks Nico. That matches exactly with my measurements. I had just accepted the tutorial code without thinking. I think you should add this as an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective transformation transforms coordinates from camera space to clip space.

Camera space is an ordinary cartesian system with the camera as the origin.

Clip space is a temporary space that is afterwards mapped to the viewport. Both `x` and `y` coordinates are in the range `[-1, 1]` for points that are within the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, Nico. Is there any meaning to the z value in clip space, or can it safely be discarded?

Comment: Usually this is the value that is written to the z-buffer. A value of 0 means that the pixel is `znear` units far from the camera (only regarding the distance along the view direction), a value of 1 means that the pixel is `zfar` units away. So basically it is the depth of the pixel, but it's not linear. You can discard it if you don't need the depth.